# How to reuse weights in MultiRNNCell?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I would like to create a new MultiRNNCell while reusing the old weights.

Starting from TensorFlow 1.1 when you create MultiRNNCell, you have to explicitly create new cells. To reuse weights you have to provide a `reuse=True` flag. In my code I currently have:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn

def create_lstm_multicell():
    lstm_cell = lambda: rnn.LSTMCell(nstates, reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)
    lstm_multi_cell = rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell() for _ in range(n_layers)])
    return lstm_multi_cell
```

When I create a first multicell the function should work as expected, and every cell inside multilayer element has independent weights and biases.

```
with tf.variable_scope('lstm') as scope:
    lstm1 = create_lstm_multicell()
```

Now I would like to create another one:

```
with tf.variable_scope('lstm') as scope:
    scope.reuse_variables()
    lstm2 = create_lstm_multicell()
```

I would like the first cell from `lstm2` to use the weights and biases of first cell from `lstm1`, second cell to reuse weights and biases of the second cell, etc. But I suspect that since I call `rnn.LSTMCell` with `reuse=True`, weights & biases of the *first* cell will be reused all the time.

1. How do I ensure that weights are reused properly?
2. If they are not, how to force this desired behavior?

P.S. For the architectural reason I do not want to reuse `lstm1`, I would like to create a new multicell `lstm2` having the same weights.

Comment: what do you mean by reusing your weights? do you want to build a stateful lstm?

Comment: @dv3 no, I do not need statefu LSTM. I just want lstm1 and lstm2 to behave identically, i.e. weights of every cell in multicell should identical between lstm1 and lstm2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

It seems that in the code from the question weights and biases of cells will be reused properly. Multicells `lstm1` and `lstm2` will have identical behavior, and cells inside MultiRNNCell will have independent weights and biases. I.e. in a *pseudocode*:

```
lstm1._cells[0].weights == lstm2._cells[0].weights
lstm1._cells[1].weights == lstm2._cells[1].weights
```

**Longer version**

This is not a definitive answer so far, but that is result of research I made so far.

It looks like a hack, but we can override the `get_variable` method to see which variables are accessed. For example like this:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import variable_scope as vs

def verbose(original_function):
    # make a new function that prints a message when original_function starts and finishes
    def new_function(*args, **kwargs):
        print('get variable:', '/'.join((tf.get_variable_scope().name, args[0])))
        result = original_function(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return new_function

vs.get_variable = verbose(vs.get_variable)
```

Now we can run the following modified code:

```
def create_lstm_multicell(name):
    def lstm_cell(i, s):
        print('creating cell %i in %s' % (i, s))
        return rnn.LSTMCell(nstates, reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)
    lstm_multi_cell = rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell(i, name) for i in range(n_layers)])
    return lstm_multi_cell

with tf.variable_scope('lstm') as scope:
    lstm1 = create_lstm_multicell('lstm1')
    layer1, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm1, x, dtype=tf.float32)
    val_1 = tf.reduce_sum(layer1)

with tf.variable_scope('lstm') as scope:
    scope.reuse_variables()
    lstm2 = create_lstm_multicell('lstm2')
    layer2, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm2, x, dtype=tf.float32)
    val_2 = tf.reduce_sum(layer2)
```

The output will look like this (I removed repetitive lines):

```
creating cell 0 in lstm1
creating cell 1 in lstm1
get variable: lstm/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/weights
get variable: lstm/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/biases
get variable: lstm/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/weights
get variable: lstm/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/biases
creating cell 0 in lstm2
creating cell 1 in lstm2
get variable: lstm/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/weights
get variable: lstm/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/biases
get variable: lstm/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/weights
get variable: lstm/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/biases
```

This output indicates that `lstm1` and `lstm2` cells will use the same weights & biases, both have separates weights & biases for the first and second cells inside MultiRNNCell.

Additionally, `val_1` and `val_2` which are outputs of `lstm1` and `lstm2` are identical during optimization.

I think MultiRNNCell creates namespaces `cell_0`, `cell_1` etc. inside of it. And therefore the weights between `lstm1` and `lstm2` will be reused.